Adding up to 3 digits number with carry over 1000 in assembly
This is the code I have tried and it only works with 3 digits numbers but the sum does not exceed 1000 for adding 3 digit numbers that exceeds 1000 just outputs 1000. I also have a problem fixing adding 1 and 2 digit numbers as inputting 1 and 2 digits numbers results in invalid character. I am confused and been working with this code for 6 hours now and still haven't fixed it.
sum segment
    assume cs:sum, ds:sum, ss:sum
    org 0100h

program: 
    jmp begin
    var1 db 0Dh, 0Ah, 'ADD NUMBERS PLEASE','$' 
    var2 db 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Add 2 Numbers.','$' 
    var3 db 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Input any number (0-999):', '$' 
    var4 db 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Input any number (0-999):', '$' 
    var5 db 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Sum:','$'

    num11 db 0
    num12 db 0
    num13 db 0
    num21 db 0
    num22 db 0
    num23 db 0
    sum1 db 0
    sum2 db 0
    sum3 db 0
    sum4 db 0

    var6 db 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Invalid Character','$'
    var7 db 0Dh, 0Ah, 'Do you want to repeat (y/n):','$'

    showstr proc
        mov ah, 09h
        int 21h
        ret
    showstr endp

    clearscr proc 
        push bx 
        mov al, 00h
        mov bh, 0Fh
        mov ah, 06h
        int 10h
        pop bx 
        ret
    clearscr endp

checknum1 proc 
    cmp al, '0'
    jb invalid_char1
    cmp al, '9'
    ja invalid_char1 
    ret
valid_char1: 
    ret
invalid_char1:
    mov dx, offset var6 
    call showstr 
    jmp num1
checknum1 endp

checknum2 proc 
    cmp al, '0'
    jb invalid_char1
    cmp al, '0'
    ja invalid_char1
    ret
valid_char2: 
    ret
invalid_char2:
    mov dx, offset var6 
    call showstr 
    jmp num2
checknum2 endp

    add_digit1 proc 
        sub bh, '0'
        sub bl, '0'
        add bh, bl
        cmp bh, 9
        ja carry1 
        jmp nocarry1
    carry1: 
        sub bh, 10
        inc sum2
        ret
    nocarry1:
        add sum1, bh
        ret
    add_digit1 endp

    add_digit2 proc 
        sub bh, '0'
        sub bl, '0'
        add bh, bl
        cmp bh, 9
        ja carry2
        jmp nocarry2 
    carry2:
        sub bh, 10
        inc sum3
        ret
    nocarry2:
        add sum2, bh
        ret
    add_digit2 endp

    add_digit3 proc 
        sub bh, '0'
        sub bl, '0'
        add bh, bl
        cmp bh, 9
        ja carry3 
        jmp nocarry3 
    carry3:
        sub bh, 10
        inc sum4
        ret
    nocarry3:
        add sum3, bh 
        ret
    add_digit3 endp

    repeatprog proc 
        cmp al, 'y'
        je begin 
        jmp exit
    repeatprog endp

begin:
    mov ax, sum
    mov ds, ax
    mov sum1, 0
    mov sum2, 0
    mov sum3, 0
    mov sum4, 0
    call clearscr
    mov dx, offset var1 
    call showstr

num1:
    lea dx, var3 
    call showstr
    mov ah, 01h 
    int 21h
    call checknum1
    mov num13, al
    mov ah, 01h 
    int 21h
    call checknum1
    mov num12, al
    mov ah, 01h 
    int 21h
    call checknum1
    mov num11, al

num2:
    lea dx, var4 
    call showstr
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    call checknum2
    mov num23, al
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    call checknum2
    mov num22, al
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    call checknum2
    mov num21, al
    mov bl, num11 
    mov bh, num21 
    call add_digit1
    mov bl, num12 
    mov bh, num22 
    call add_digit2
    mov bl, num13 
    mov bh, num23 
    call add_digit3
    lea dx, var5
    call showstr
    mov dl, sum4
    add dl, '0' 
    mov ah, 02h 
    int 21h

    mov dl, sum3 
    add dl, '0'
    mov ah, 02h 
    int 21h

    mov dl, sum2
    add dl, '0'
    mov ah, 02h 
    int 21h

    mov dl, sum1
    add dl, '0'
    mov ah, 02h 
    int 21h

    lea dx, var7 
    call showstr 
    mov ah, 01h 
    int 21h
    call repeatprog

exit:
    mov ah, 4ch
    int 21h

sum ends 
end program

I have tried this fix but it still won't work:
checknum1 proc 
    cmp al, '0'
    jb invalid_char1
    cmp al, '9'
    ja invalid_char1 
    ret
valid_char1: 
    ret
invalid_char1:
    mov dx, offset var6 
    call showstr 
    jmp num1
checknum1 endp

checknum2 proc 
    cmp al, '0'
    jb invalid_char2
    cmp al, '9'
    ja invalid_char2 
    ret
valid_char2: 
    ret
invalid_char2:
    mov dx, offset var6 
    call showstr 
    jmp num2
checknum2 endp


What have you done to debug this yourself? You're doing yourself and others a disservice by using completely nondescript variable names.


I also have a problem fixing adding 1 and 2 digit numbers as inputting 1 and 2 digits numbers results in invalid character.

Don't worry about this and concentrate on the 3-digit numbers first. You've got some fixing to do!

Whenever you call a proc like in call checknum1 you mandatory need to return from that proc via the ret instruction. That is the normal way to do this and it keeps the stack balanced. So it is that jmp num1 in the checknum1 proc that you need to replace by a ret instruction. One problem remains: how to tell success from failure? Well normally we'd clear the carry to indicate success, and we'd set the carry to indicate failure. Later upon having returned from the proc, we inspect the carry and act accordingly, which in your case is just jumping back to the top of num1:
checknum1 proc 
    cmp  al, '0'
    jb   invalid_char1
    cmp  al, '9'
    ja   invalid_char1 
    CLC               ; success
    ret
invalid_char1:
    mov  dx, offset var6 
    call showstr 
    STC               ; failure
    ret
checknum1 endp

...

num1:
    lea  dx, var3 
    call showstr
    mov  ah, 01h 
    int  21h
    call checknum1    ; -> AL CF
    JC   num1
    mov  num13, al
    mov  ah, 01h 
    int  21h
    call checknum1    ; -> AL CF
    JC   num1
    mov  num12, al
    mov  ah, 01h 
    int  21h
    call checknum1    ; -> AL CF
    JC   num1
    mov  num11, al

Of course, you need a similar modification for the second number.
And the repeatprog proc should not even exist as a proc! Just keep those few lines in the main loop:
    ...
    mov  ah, 01h 
    int  21h
    cmp  al, 'y'
    jne  exit       ; Reversed condition because you need
    jmp  begin      ; the NEAR range that only JMP can offer
exit:


The add_digit series of proc's is incomplete! If the addition results in a value of 10 or more, you not only need to increment the next higher sum, but also add the remainder from the subtraction of 10 to the current sum:
add_digit1 proc 
    sub  bx, '00'
    add  bh, bl
    cmp  bh, 9
    jbe  nocarry1
    inc  sum2
    sub  bh, 10
  nocarry1:
    add  sum1, bh
    ret
add_digit1 endp

This is already better but still not fully correct! At least for the digits that follow could the add sum2, bh and add sum3, bh produce another carry that you should deal with.
add_digit2 proc 
    sub  bx, '00'
    add  bh, bl
    cmp  bh, 9
    jbe  nocarry2
    inc  sum3
    sub  bh, 10
  nocarry2:
    add  sum2, bh
    cmp  sum2, 9
    jbe  done
    inc  sum3
  done:
    ret
add_digit2 endp


The clearscr proc is missing some parameters! The coordinates for the upperleft and lowerright corners were not included.
clearscr proc 
    push bx
    mov  dx, 184Fh    ; lowerright (79,24)
    xor  cx, cx       ; upperleft (0,0)
    mov  bh, 0Fh
    mov  ax, 0600h
    int  10h
    pop  bx 
    ret
clearscr endp

